# Issue adding a Access File as a Data Source in Visual Studio

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Good evening,

I seem to be having an issue with adding a Access Database as a Data Source in my Visual Studio project. When I launch the New Data Source wizard and go through the first two steps I land at the 'Choose Your Data Connection' window, where I have to choose 'New Connection...'. Once this window has opened I choose the first option which is 'Microsoft Access Database File' and this is where I'm having my issue. It seems the way that it is supposed to work, and how it works for everyone I know, is that it is supposed to open a New Connection window similar to this:

(This is a screenshot I grabbed off Google as I cannot actually get to this step, I realize it's an old photo but this is generally what I'm supposed to see)

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWIF5.jpg)

What I actually get is this:

[Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtHbW.jpg)

And that's where I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this issue, running the Windows System File Checker tool seems to repair it. To run, open a command prompt as administrator and type:

sfc /scannow

Once that completes (it may take a while), reboot and you should be good to go.